# "Spread types may only be created from object type" error in Angular 13 CRUD project

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, crud

I'm creating a CRUD  app in angular 13 and I get this error with firebase and I get this error:

```
"Spread types may only be created from object types"
```

this is my code

```
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service:EmployeeService) { }
  list: Employee[] =  [];
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.getEmployees().subscribe(actionArray =>{
      this.list = actionArray.map(item =>{
        return {
          id : item.payload.doc.id,
          ...item.payload.doc.data()
        } as Employee
      })
    });
  }

}
```

the error is referring to this line:

```
...item.payload.doc.data()
```

Comment: Should it be ...item.payload.doc.data? In your code example you are trying to call data() like a function which I'm guessing its just data?

Comment: it is a function. look: https://ibb.co/nc5jNMq

Answer (score 0):

See the return type of `item.payload.doc.data()` in the [screenshot](https://ibb.co/nc5jNMq) you attached.

The return type is `unknown`. Even if the object you are receiving is spreadable, typescript will show this compile time error. You can try something like the following:

```
return {
  id : item.payload.doc.id,
  ...(item.payload.doc.data() as Record<string,any>)
} as Employee
```

Whether that will satisify the `Employee` interface I'm not sure. Otherwise you could try replace the `Record<string,any>` with `Employee`.

**Note**
We are not seeing your employee service in the code extract here. If you look at the screenshot again, it seems like Firebase allows you to define the type when integrating with Firebase.

The `QueryDocumentSnaphot<unkown>.data` eludes to that fact that you didn't specify which type you are expecting back from the Firebase integration. When you are invoking the Firebase SDK/module (however you are using it), you should have the option to specify the interface you are expecting back as a generic.

If you were to do that, you shouldn't have the problem you are having currently.

It's been ages since I've looked at Firebase, so I stress **this is not a real implementation** and you would have to further consult their documentation on where or how to specify the generic type, but the following is a common pattern.

```
import {Firebase} from 'firebase';
import {Employee} from './employee.interface.ts';

export class EmployeeService {
  getEmployees() {
    return Firebase.getRecords<Employee>('some/path/or/resource');
  }
}
```